# SSH: instruct backgrounded tunnel to exit on broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I frequently start background SSH tunnels using the `... -f -N -L ...` options. This works great, until for example I sleep my machine, or my VPN credentials expire, when the tunnels stop working and I have to dig through the output of `ps` to kill the old ones and restart. The symptom of the broken tunnels is a "Broken pipe".

Is there any way to instruct the `ssh` process to exit when its pipe breaks? Then I could just restart my SSH tunnels when they die, and skip `ps`.

Comment: autossh manages that, I *think*

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to set [ServerAliveInterval](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ServerAliveInterval) to something higher then default 0(never)

And instead of running those tunnels into background (with -f) I'd put it into systemd units with Restart=always option

Comment: ServerAliveInterval doesn't help with for example a laptop, which sleeps/loses connectivity frequently. And the systemd unit would only know to restart the process if it dies, which SSH tunnels don't do for broken pipes. If I could instruct the tunnel to die on a broken tunnel that would help a a lot.